# How can I have working auto certificate renewal when using custom path in k8s ingress

Tags: kubernetes, ingress-nginx, url-rewrite

In our k8s cluster we have multiple services, reachable from public internet, we're using nginx ingresses for routing + let's encrypt for certificate management.
As we're using custom rewrite rule and custom path for our service the auto renewal of the certificates does not work, at least that's my understanding.

My questions :

1. Is my understanding of the issue correct ?
2. How can I have the auto certificate renewal working with our current rewrite rule + custom path ?

Here is an example of the ingress.yml we're using :

````
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <REDACTED>
  namespace: <REDACTED>
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: <REDACTED>
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 16m
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "<REDACTED>"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: <REDACTED>
    hosts:
    - <REDACTED>
  rules:
  - host: <REDACTED>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /<REDACTED>/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: <REDACTED>
            port:
              number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
```
````